# SQLiteException: near /TABLE_NAME/: syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax, tablename

please help me. I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "values": syntax error: CREATE TABLE values (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name text, caption text, lines integer , photo_url text, type text);
```

Here is how I'm trying to create db table:

```
private static final String TABLE_VALUES_CREATE =
    "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_VALUES +
           " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
          + ValueTemplate.KEY_NAME + " text, "
          + ValueTemplate.KEY_CAPTION + " text, "
          + ValueTemplate.KEY_LINES + " integer , "
          + ValueTemplate.KEY_PHOTOURL + " text, "
          + ValueTemplate.KEY_TYPE + " text);";

   //ValueTemplate class:
   // VALUE TEMPLATES

      public static final String KEY_CAPTION = "caption";
      public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
      public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
      public static final String KEY_LINES = "lines";
      public static final String KEY_PHOTOURL = "photo_url";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think because (values) is a reserved name, rename your table..

Answer (score 3):

The name of your table (`values`) is a keyword reserved by SQLite.

See here for the list of keywords: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on keeping the exact same table name then try `[values]`, otherwise the best would be to rename it to something like `tblValues`